# Обращение к базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер. У меня имеется БД и в ней таблица profiles со столбцами pid, login, password. Добавил значение: 0 admin password(admin). 
Пытаюсь к ней обратиться таким скриптом:

```
<?php
$response = array();
require 'config.php';
$base = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($base);
if(isset($_GET["login"]) and isset($_GET["password"])){
    $login = $_GET["login"];
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE login ='".$login."'");
    if(!empty($res)){
        $arr = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $pass = $_GET["password"];

        if($arr["login"] == $login and $arr["password"] == "admin")
        {
            $response["Success"] = 1;
        }
        else{
            $response["Success"] = 0;
            $response["Error"] = 1;
        }
        }
    else {
        $response["Success"] = 0;
        $response["Error"] = 2;
        }
    }
else {
    $response["Success"] = 0;
    $response["Error"] = 3;
    }
echo json_encode($response);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Даже если выполнить запрос

```
my.site/file.php?login=admin&password=admin
```

То все равно всегда $res пустой. Использую денвер. В чем может быть проблема?

config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_AUTH', 'users');
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
?>
```

Comment: у вас наверно выключены ошибки. Включите и увидете причину.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указываете с какой базой данной вы хотите работать

```
$db = mysql_select_db('db_name', $base);
```

Вы можете дальше проверить

```
if($db && isset($_GET["login"]) && isset($_GET["password"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с ответом выше. Также с выходом последнего php, рекомендуется подключаться к БД посредством ООП, в php для этого есть свои классы. (Хотя мне кажется это дело вкуса). Для вашего случая:

```html
<?php try
{
 $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=название вашей БД', 'root', '');
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"'); 
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
 $output = 'Невозможно подключиться к серверу баз данных' . $e->getMessage();
 echo $output;
 exit();
}
if(isset($_GET["login"]) and isset($_GET["password"])){
    $login = $_GET["login"];
 try
{
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE login ='".$login."'";
 $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
 $output = 'Ошибка при выполнении обновления: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
 echo $output;
 exit();
}
$row = $result->fetch();
$pas = $_REQUEST['password'];
if(!empty($row)){
  if($row["login"] == $login and $row["password"] == $pas)
        {
            $response["Success"] = 1;
        }
        else{
            $response["Success"] = 0;
            $response["Error"] = 1;
        }

}else{
 $response["Success"] = 0;
    $response["Error"] = 2;
}
}else{
 $response["Success"] = 0;
    $response["Error"] = 3;
}
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
?>
```

Введите свои пароль, хостинг, имя БД, логин в первую строчку.

Comment: Для меня это пока что сложно) Просто пишу минисервер для основного проекта, но все равно спасибо большое)

Comment: Все приходит с опытом)